# PowerApp Custom Cards Issues

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Recently i customized my SharePoint form using PowerApps. After unlocking and customizing some of my columns, the columns converted into custom cards and have no entry into my original SharePoint List columns. So When i fill out the form and submit, those custom column don't update on SharePoint column tables. How do i get around this and ensure my custom cards field reflect on my original SharePoint Column tables when submitted?

[POWER APP COLUMS CONVERTED TO CUSTOM CARDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDOQx.png) [COLUMS NOT BEEN UPDATED IN THE LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEFns.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the following properties to see if you somehow ended up modifying them when you unlocked the data card?

- In PowerApps Studio, select your Data Card and in the property pane, go to Advanced.
- Under DataField you should see the name of the field the card is mapped to.

  - Note that this is the internal name used by SharePoint list. If you want to validate that the field name is correct you can go to your SharePoint site > List settings > Edit the column that the data card is connected to. In the query string you should see "&Field" parameter with the field name as the value.
- In PowerApps Studio also validate that Default is also set to ThisItem.[DataField from step above] and Update is set to Value(DataCardValue[N].Text).

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you unlock a DataCard it becomes "Custom". You are likely missing a "Submit" button or the like on your Customized Sharepoint Form. Add a button and set its OnSelect property to `SubmitForm(SharePointForm1)`.